# conditions in sumifs formula

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

The main worksheet in my workbook `equities` has information on stock trading activity on a daily basis:

[image: img]

I have created a new worksheet titled `monthly commission`, from which I would like to have commission figures (column `L` on the equities page) on a month by month basis:

[image]

I have attempted to use a SUMIFS formula however this has not worked. It may be due to the way the dates being listed being different (Standard date format on the main equities sheet, 05/09/2018 etc) whereas as the screenshot demonstrates its month and year on the new worksheet. I've also included an example of the sumifs I tried to use

`=SUMIFS(Equities!L:L,Equities!A:A,Monthly Commission!A3,Equities!A:A,">=1/10/2018",Equities!A:A,"<=31/10/2018")`

If anyone can perhaps suggest where I'm going wrong with this or where the error is in my formula it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest using a [**Pivot Table**](https://support.office.com/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) instead.  Summaries by month (or by any other field or datepart) is what Pivot Tables are *for*.

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg. The data involved in the worksheet is updated continuously so I'm not sure if a pivot table is the most feasible method

Comment: What's in Monthly Commission cell A3?

Comment: @XORLX Hi it is the month/year, Oct-18.

Comment: What's the actual (1) cell value and (2) cell formatting for that entry?

Comment: Cell value = 01/10/2018 Cell formatting = Oct-18. Strange, I just noticed how it lists the date.

Comment: In that case your 3 conditions for the values in column A, i.e. that they are simultaneously (1) equal to the value in Commission!A3 (which we know is 01/10/2018; (2) >=1/10/2018; 3) <=31/10/2018 are logically reducible to just the first of those 3 (the other two being made redundant by the first), and will only ever be satisfied by one value, namely 1/10/2018.

Comment: Do you know how I might be able to edit the formula in order to satisfy the criteria of the commission values falling between the dates of 01/10/2018 to 31/10/2018?

Comment: I presume you've now removed the condition that it's precisely equal to 01/10/2018?

Comment: Can you highlight the condition if its not too much trouble? I've tried a few options and nothing has worked

Comment: You have 3 conditions relating to Equities!A:A: (1) =Monthly Commission!A3; (2) >=1/10/2018; (3) <=31/10/2018. If Monthly Commission!A3 is 01/01/2018, then the above can be rewritten as:(1) =01/01/2018; (2) >=1/10/2018; (3) <=31/10/2018. I leave it to you to decide which of those should be removed.

Comment: =SUMIFS(Equities!L:L,Equities!A:A,">=1/10/2018",Equities!A:A,"<=31/10/2018") I have tried this but it returns a TRUE value. I thought I had removed the correct criteria

Comment: I don't understand. SUMIFS can never return TRUE; only a number or an error.

Comment: the above formula I posted returned TRUE

Comment: That's not possible, as I said. There must be something else that didn't paste.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are right and the issue comes from the date formatting. But not only.

**EDIT:**

The spreadsheet naming is not correct in your example, instead of:

> Monthly Commission!A3

You should have:

> 'Monthly Commission'!A3

**EDIT 2:**

Make sure that the logic of your formula also makes sense. In the example that you gave, the conditions to fulfil are the following:

1. Equal to first of November 2018
2. Older or equal to first of October 2018
3. Newer or equal to 31st of October 2018

This will always return 0 as there are no date that could possibly match all three conditions.

**Before edits**

The first formatting issues appears in your formula. To fix that, use the function "DATEVALUE":

```
=SUMIFS(Equities!L:L,Equities!L:L,'Monthly Commission'!A3,Equities!L:L,">=" & DATEVALUE("1/10/2018"),Equities!L:L,"<=" & DATEVALUE("31/10/2018"))
```

If the issue persists, maybe it is because of the way the dates are entered in your equity sheet. You need to make sure that they are "excel dates". An helper column (let's say the column O) can be used with DATEVALUE. Your formula becomes:

```
=SUMIFS(Equities!L:L,Equities!O:O,'Monthly Commission'!A3,Equities!O:O,">=" & DATEVALUE("1/10/2018"),Equities!O:O,"<=" & DATEVALUE("31/10/2018"))
```

The formula in the column O would simply be:

```
=DATEVALUE(L)
```

Another solution, which does not require the use of an helper column, is to leverage the sumproduct function. It can work just like a sumifs:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Equities!L:L)*(DATEVALUE(Equities!L:L)='Monthly Commission'!A3)*(DATEVALUE(Equities!L:L)>=DATEVALUE("1/10/2018"))*(DATEVALUE(Equities!L:L)<=DATEVALUE("31/10/2018")))
```

As a side note, if you get the result "#VALUE" for the DATEVALUE function, this means that you have dates that are already being assessed as numbers. Hence you can discard the DATEVALUE wrapper and directly use the cell reference.

Comment: Hi @GPTV, thank you for the suggestions. I have tried them but unfortunately no luck thus far. The formula with DATEVALUE did not return any results, and the SUMPRODUCT approach gives me a #VALUE! output. As an aside, whenever I input a formula excel prompts me to open a file, does anyone know why this is?

Comment: @NHure92 "whenever I input a formula excel prompts me to open a file". This is because of the "sheet name" which is invalid, I had not noticed this error earlier. See edit in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you, it no longer prompts me to open a file. However, the SUMIF suggestion and the SUMPRODUCT approach both continue to return #VALUE!

Comment: @NHure92 I did not account for your table limits but accounting for that should help you. For instance, your equity table starts on row 2, assuming it ends on row XXX(last non empty row of your equity sheet), you should replace ALL the "L:L" by "$L$3:$L$XXX". Also look at my edit on the conditions.